# Can a "Microsoft.Resources/deployments" dependsOn another "Microsoft.Resources/deployments" in Azure ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I want to 1st deploy a resource group, next deploy a bunch of resources (say a storage account and a keyvault), and finally create some Key Vault secrets (secret with the key to the storage account created in previous step).

this is how i define my resources

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "location": "[parameters('RgLocation')]",
        "name": "[variables('RgName')]",
        "properties": {},
        "tags": "[variables('ResourceTags')]"
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "name": "resourcesDeployment",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('RgName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', variables('RgName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
        "name": "secretsDeployment",
        "resourceGroup": "[variables('RgName')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'resourcesDeployment')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
           ...                
        }
    }
]
```

the resourcesDeployment "dependsOn" the resource group, which works perfectly/as expected.

the secretsDeployment "dependsOn" resourcesDeployment and this is the part that fails. I'm getting this error:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/resourcesDeployment' is not defined in
>   the template.

How do I ensure that these deployments happen in order.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: this is subscription level, right? try this dependsOn: `"[resourceId(variables('RgName') ,'Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'resourcesDeployment')]"`

Comment: @Nandun All you need is a storage account and a key vault with secret to be created right ?

Comment: @HariHaran - yes that is the bare minimum I need.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: We ended up creating 2 separate ARM templates. first one deployed the RG and the resources. once that was complete, we run the 2nd template to create the secrets.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem and.. the solution will surprise you - you don't do dependson `Microsoft.Resources/deployments/blah` but rather just the name of the first deployment resource, e.g.:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "firstDeployment",
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "secondDeployment",
      "dependsOn": [
        "firstDeployment"
      ],
    }
```